# Eclipse RCP terminologies and concepts

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I am just starting to develop some application using Eclipse RCP. I was able to hack out a prototype by reading some tutorials. Although I was able to hack out some working code, I found myself shaky on some of the RCP concepts like:

- What is a page? I see a lot of getActivePage() API calls, so I am assuming there can be multiple pages am I correct?
- In the IWorkbechPart API there is an API called getSite(), which is being use a lot, but I am not sure what is a "site"

The above are just a sample of questions I am having, so it would really help me if someone can point me to some articles explain these type of concepts (I did google around without success).

I would also appreciate it if someone can point me to some articles that can educate me on how to write clean RCP code; kind of like the "Effective Java" for RCP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the JavaDoc for the Interfaces, they are well documented and give you an idea of the terminology. For example:

> What is a page?

Look at the Javadoc at `org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPage`

> called getSite(),

Look at the Javadoc at `org.eclipse.ui.IViewSite`

Answer (score 3):

You may want to [check this](http://blog.eclipse-tips.com/2009/09/back-to-basics-display-shell-window.html) as well:

Comment: No problem. I'm here only to help the Eclipse community. Not to earn badges with right answers. I can't pay my bills with that anyways :-)