# What does a " site " signify OR represent in the eclipse ( rcp ? ) world?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I just can't find a definition  of this term(  in the eclipse context). Somebody enlighten me please

LE Examples: IWorkbenchSite , IViewSite etc

Comment: Look at the answers on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564248/eclipse-rcp-terminologies-and-concepts - there's a [link](http://blog.eclipse-tips.com/2009/09/back-to-basics-display-shell-window.html) there

Comment: I'm confused... why is IViewSite  created if it is just going to be an interface with no children ? .... AND CAN SOMEONE, PLEASE, explain to me what a "site" is, in layman's terms?..

Answer (score 0):

The interface obviously has children, but they are all internal to Eclipse implementation. A "site" is just a way for a part to access the workbench. See http://blog.eclipse-tips.com/2009/09/back-to-basics-display-shell-window.html.